# AngularJS forEach .push undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS (started this week) and I want to pull a couple of items out of the $http.post returned data and create a new object $scope.tests.latLngAll with a subset of the data.

If I do the below with .push in the forEach I get an error that $scope.tests.latLngAll is undefined even though I am trying to define it in line 4.

```
$scope.tester = function( ){    

$scope.tests = {};
$scope.tests.latLngAll = {};

$http.post( '/src/shops.php' , $scope.postdata )
    .success( function(data) {

    $scope.tests = data;

    angular.forEach( $scope.tests, function( value, key ){ 
        $scope.tests.latLngAll.push( { key :  value } ); 
        }); 
    })          
}
```

If I replace the .push with '=' the last item in the array is the only value assigned to $scope.tests.latLngAll which makes sense.

$scope.tests.latLngAll = ( { key :  value } );

I assume this means the data is there and accessible through forEach 'value' but I am not doing the push right.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Push is for an array. Try initializing your variable to []

Comment: BTW if you want to end up with a single hash (rather than an array of hashes) 
use angulars extend method http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.exten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The undefined 'latLngAll' problem is caused by the data. You have to make sure that the data must contains a array object named 'latLngAll'. If you want to add latLngAll dynamically, you could try this:

```
$scope.tester = function( ){    

  $scope.tests = {};
  //$scope.tests.latLngAll = {};

  $http.post( '/src/shops.php' , $scope.postdata )
    .success( function(data) {

    $scope.tests = data;

    var tempArr = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.tests, function(value,key){
     tempArr.push( { key :  value } );
    });
    $scope.tests.latlngAll=tempArr;
    console.log($scope.tests.latlngAll);
  });          
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77K3u/).

Comment: +1 for saving me some time on this angular.forEach() and attaching returned data onto scope object

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scope.tests.latLngAll = {};
```

Replace To:

```
$scope.tests.latLngAll = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.tester = function( ){    

    $scope.tests = [];
    $scope.tests.latLngAll = [];

    $http.post( '/src/shops.php' , $scope.postdata )
        .success( function(data) {

        $scope.tests = data;

      angular.forEach($scope.tests, function(value, key){
           this.push(key + ': ' + value);
       }, $scope.tests.latLngAll);
        });       
    }
```